# Why does $variable not return the most recently assigned value of variable in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, variables

For example:

```
variable="version1"
filename="Testfile_$variable"
echo $filename
variable="version2"
echo $filename
filename="Testfile_$variable"
echo $filename
```

produces the output:

```
Testfile_version1
Testfile_version1
Testfile_version2
```

Why does it only changes the value of `filename` to "Testfile_version2" after explicitly reassigning a value to `filename` after changing `variable`? I would think when the second `echo $filename` is called it would check back for the value of `filename`, see that it has `$variable` in it, look for the value of `variable` and see that the value has changed, and then put that value into `filename`, but it seems this is not the case.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash performs full variable expansion every time it is evaluating an expression. That is

```
    filename="Testfile_$variable"
```

can be interpreted as

1. Evaluate the expression `"Testfile_$variable"` performing variable expansion.
2. Assign the resulting string to variable `$filename`.

Therefore any further changes to `$variable` would not affect the value of `$filename`.

You can somehow get closer to your desired behaviour using functions instead of variables

```
get_filename(){
  filename="Testfile_$variable"
  echo $filename
}

variable=version1
get_filename
variable=version2
get_filename
```

Would print different lines without explicitly reassigning the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`filename` isn't storing a reference to `variable`, it's storing the literal string that is produced in the assignment (`Testfile_version1`). So you have to re-assign `filename` in order to reflect changes to `variable`

Answer (score 0):

It's just how it works. The shell doesn't keep track of which variables a variable depends on - there's no "references" or pointers here.

When you do `filename="Testfile_$variable"`, the shell fetches the current value of `$variable` and builds the new variable `filename` out of `$variable`.

In other words, it copies the contents of `$variable` instead of referencing.

Answer (score 0):

The value of variable is looked up and added to the prefix Testfile_ in the first assignment to filename.  After that, changing the value of variable doesn't retroactively update the value of filename.

Another way to think about this is if you had just done filename = $variable.  Would you then expect changes to the value of variable to change the value of filename?

More specifically, the value of the variable filename is a string that is computed by taking a template string and substituting some values (the value of variable in this case) into it.  Once that substitution is done the value of filename is just a string, and has no knowledge of how it got that value.

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluated once at the time of use.

I.e., `$filename` isn't `Testfile_$variable`, it's the result of evaluating that expression.